# What is the easiest way to serialize a UIManagedDocument for cloud backup?

Tags: objective-c, serialization, salesforce, nsdata, uimanageddocument

I'm looking to convert the UIManagedDocument to NSData, but its a package directory. The ultimate goal is to upload to Salesforce and recreate from there if the app needs to be reinstalled. The alternative (extracting all the elements from the document) appears too onerous and error prone.

Is it safe to simply make an NSFileWrapper of the UIManagedDocument package? Or could any of the files be in an inconsistent state?